# Magento 2 How to add to wishlist on checkout Summary page

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, database

I want to add to the wishlist link on the checkout summary page under the product section.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. create `checkout_cart_index.xml` on following location.
   app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/layout/

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
            <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
                 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.cart.custom.block" after="-" template="Vendor_Extension::custom-block.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
2. now create `custom-block.phtml` on following location and put the Button code over there.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/templates/

```
<?php
echo "YOUR BUTTON CODE HERE";
```